# Flash effect from camera in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have created a polaroid camera in Unity. We are able to take pictures and instantiate new polaroids which spawn near the player. We have a flash effect but the problem is that the flash is not displayed in the image taken.

Additionally, I have tried adjusting the position of the camera flash effect to see if it would appear in the captured image, but it still does not show up. We have also experimented with changing the camera's lighting settings, but this did not affect the captured image either. Any suggestions on how to fix this issue would be greatly appreciated.

The player also has his own flashlight. I have tried turning it on simultaneously with the flash, but it is still not displayed on the image. The flashlight is displayed on the image if the player has turned it on.

```
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class PhotoCapture:MonoBehaviour {
    [Header("Camera Item Parameters")]
    [SerializeField] public static float charges = 3;
    public static bool canUseCamera = true;

    [Header("Flash Effect")]
    [SerializeField] private GameObject cameraFlash;
    [SerializeField] private float flashTime;

    private Texture2D screenCapture;
    public static bool viewingPhoto = false;

    // All text GUI needs to be in this parent object
    [Header("GUI")]
    [SerializeField] private GameObject GUI;

    [Header("Polaroid GameObject")]
    [SerializeField] private GameObject itemPolaroid;

    // Code needed for finding specific polaroid
    private RaycastHit hitObject;
    private bool itemObject = false;
    private GameObject currentItemPolaroid;
    private GameObject currentPhotoFrame;

    void Update() {

        if(Input.GetKeyDown(FirstPersonController.useCameraButton) && canUseCamera && !viewingPhoto && charges > 0) {
            StartCoroutine(CapturePhoto());
            UseCamera();
        }
        // Raycast to see if player is looking at a Polaroid
        itemObject = Physics.Raycast(transform.position, transform.forward, out hitObject, 6f);
        if(!viewingPhoto && Input.GetKeyDown(CameraMovement.interactKey) && itemObject && hitObject.collider.gameObject.CompareTag("Polaroid")) {
            currentItemPolaroid = hitObject.collider.gameObject.transform.parent.gameObject;
            ShowPhoto();
        }

        // Close Photo
        if(viewingPhoto && Input.GetKeyDown(FirstPersonController.useCameraButton)) {
            RemovePhoto();
        }

    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Increases light intensity on object - CameraFlash
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private IEnumerator CameraFlashEffect() {
        cameraFlash.SetActive(true);
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(flashTime);
        cameraFlash.SetActive(false);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Captures the photo.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private IEnumerator CapturePhoto() {
        // Game UI set to false so that it does not show in screenshot
        GUI.SetActive(false);
        // Wait for end of frame so that the UI is not captured in the screenshot
        yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();

        // Takes a screenshot of the screen
        Rect regionToRead = new(0, 0, Screen.width, Screen.height);
        Texture2D newTexture = new(Screen.width, Screen.height, TextureFormat.RGB24, false);
        newTexture.ReadPixels(regionToRead, 0, 0, false);
        newTexture.Apply();
        screenCapture = newTexture;

        // Makes a sprite of the screenshot and places it in PhotoDisplayArea in ItemPolaroidObject
        Sprite photoSprite = Sprite.Create(screenCapture, new Rect(0.0f, 0.0f, screenCapture.width, screenCapture.height), new Vector2(0.5f, 0.5f), 100.0f);
        GameObject photoDisplayAreaObject = itemPolaroid.transform.GetChild(1).GetChild(0).GetChild(0).GetChild(1).gameObject;
        Image photoDisplayArea = photoDisplayAreaObject.GetComponent<Image>();
        photoDisplayArea.sprite = photoSprite;

        // Sets PhotoFrameBG (Blank canvas) in ItemPolaroidObject to true
        StartCoroutine(CameraFlashEffect());
        GUI.SetActive(true);
        SpawnItemPolaroid();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Shows the photo.
    /// </summary>
    public void ShowPhoto() {
        // Set viewingPhoto to true so that player cannot move
        viewingPhoto = true;
        GUI.SetActive(false);

        // Object is hardcoded and only The ItemPolaroid within the ItemPolaroid should be Tagged "Polaroid"
        // Sets PhotoFrameBG (Blank canvas) in ItemPolaroidObject to true
        currentPhotoFrame = currentItemPolaroid.transform.GetChild(1).GetChild(0).gameObject;
        currentPhotoFrame.SetActive(true);

        // Destroy the visable body of the ItemPolaroid
        GameObject currentItemPolaroidBody = currentItemPolaroid.transform.GetChild(0).gameObject;
        Destroy(currentItemPolaroidBody);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Removes the photo.
    /// </summary>
    private void RemovePhoto() {
        // Set viewingPhoto to false so that player can move
        viewingPhoto = false;
        currentPhotoFrame.SetActive(false);
        Destroy(currentItemPolaroid);
        GUI.SetActive(true);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Spawns the item polaroid in a random location around infront of the player.
    /// </summary>
    private void SpawnItemPolaroid() {
        // Random position and rotation
        Vector3 randomPosition = new(
            Random.Range(FirstPersonController.characterController.transform.position.x, FirstPersonController.characterController.transform.position.x + 0.5f),
            Random.Range(FirstPersonController.characterController.transform.position.y + 0.5f, FirstPersonController.characterController.transform.position.y + 1.5f),
            Random.Range(FirstPersonController.characterController.transform.position.z, FirstPersonController.characterController.transform.position.z + 0.5f)
            );

        Quaternion randomRotation = Random.rotation;
        // Spawn Polaroid
        GameObject newPolaroid = Instantiate(itemPolaroid, randomPosition, randomRotation);

    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Method for using camera if the button is pressed and player canUseCamera is true,
    /// charges exceed 0
    /// </summary>
    private void UseCamera() {
        charges--;
    }
}
```

I have tried taking the picture in CameraFlashEffect() but that did not work.

Comment: What is the cameraFlash? Is it visible as soon as it is active? Is it displayed in the image if it is always active?

Comment: You wont get a convincing looking flash with jsust a light object, youll need to use some vfx like a flash sprite or some post-processing shader

Comment: You are activating the flash after you've created the image.